# In MongoDB, can I run the compact command without shutting down each instance?

Tags: mongodb

In the server structure, primary, secondary, and arbiter are each physically operated.
mongo db version is 4.2.3.

Some of the documents were deleted in the oldest order because too many documents were accumulated in a specific collection.
However, even deleting documents did not release the storage area.
Upon checking, I found that mongodb's mechanism retains reusable bytes even if the document is deleted.
Also, I found out that unnecessary disk space can be freed with the [compact](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/command/compact/) command in the WiredTiger engine.

Currently, all clients connected to the db are querying using the arbiter ip and port.

Since the DB is composed only of replication, not sharding, if each individual executes the compact command independently, Even if each instance is locked, it is expected that the arbiter will distribute the query to the currently available instances.

Is this possible?

Or, Should I shutdown each instance, run it standalone, run the compact command, and then reconfigure psa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may upgrade your MonogDB to latest version 4.4. Documentation of [compact](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/compact/#behavior):

> **Blocking**
>
> Changed in version 4.4.
>
> Starting in v4.4, on WiredTiger, compact only blocks the following
> metadata operations:
>
> ```
> db.collection.drop
> db.collection.createIndex and db.collection.createIndexes
> db.collection.dropIndex and db.collection.dropIndexes
> ```
>
> compact does not block MongoDB CRUD Operations for the database it is
> currently operating on.
>
> Before v4.4, compact blocked all operations for the database it was
> compacting, including MongoDB CRUD Operations, and was therefore
> recommended for use only during scheduled maintenance periods.
> Starting in v4.4, the compact command is appropriate for use at any
> time.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone looking for the answer with 4.4 please see [this bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-14122) and the [documentation entry](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.4/reference/command/compact/#mongodb-dbcommand-dbcmd.compact) as the compact routine still forces the node to recovery state if you are running in replica set (and I assume this is the default use case for most projects)